# How can I test a change on a forked R package before sending a pull request?

Tags: r, git, github, git-fork

I have forked and cloned an R repository on my local computer. I have made some edits but I'm not sure how to test these changes before sending out a pull request.

I don't know how to make an R package from this clone one and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual two-step:

```
R CMD build directoryOfYourPackage
```

resulting in a tar.gz archive you use in the next step:

```
R CMD check package_1.2.3.tar.gz
```

where package and the version are determined by the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Both commands have options, i.e. you can suppress vignette creation and test if you have an insufficient LaTeX installation and these pdf vignettes etc pp.  See *Writing R Extensions* for all the gory details.

Also, if you are set up for Travis CI and the package is then your commit back to your fork should trigger a build at Travis doing the same: package building and check.  However, it is also a good idea to check locally before committing...